# Regex for comma-delimited list

Tags: regex

I have a form where users can enter unique identifiers in a comma-delimited list with a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 8 entered at any given time. There will be no spacing.

Format:

```
eee23775-8bd4-4cf6-bd98-b08e630210ce
```

This is an example:

```
e6e23775-8bd4-4cf6-bd98-b08e630210ce,e4523775-8bd4-4cf6-bd00-b08e630210ce,eee23775-8bd4-4cf6-bd98-b08e630210ce,e4523775-8bd4-4cf6-bd00-b08e630210ce
```

What is the best way to build a regex for the above?

The regex should not allow

- Special characters outside [-][,]
- No spaces

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){0,7}$
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
^(([a-f\d]{4})(?:(?2)-){4}(?2){3})(?:,(?1)){0,7}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T4NHW2/1)